# FOSS system image backup software for Windows?

Tags: windows, open-source, backup, disk-image

Is there a FOSS backup software for Windows (10) that does system/disk images?

There are non-FOSS options such as AOMEI, Paragon, etc.

There are also many FOSS backup software, but most seem to focus on file/directory backups. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software#Free_and_open-source_software

There is Clonezilla which is great, but it cannot make "hot" images. i.e. the disk must be unmounted, and that is not practical for regular automated backups.

Ideally, also looking for compression, de-duplication, automated scheduling, and retention policies. But the first question is what, if any, are the options in this category?

Answer (score 2):

[UrBackup](https://www.urbackup.org/) does image backups while the system is running. Restore is done via a live Linux. Perhaps important compared to what you mentioned is that it works over the network, that is the images are transferred to a server and stored there. You can run the server on the same machine as the client but it won't be as efficient as software that backs up directly to local disk.

It can

- Compress the disk image
- Automatically schedule backups
- It has automatic retention + archiving for configuring how long you want to keep the images

Deduplication is up to the file system, so perhaps use it with ZFS, btrfs or Windows deduplication if you want this.

UrBackup is an FOSS client/server backup system developed in part by me.

Comment: I was thinking more of a serverless, zero-trust option, but the client/server model has the advantage of better ransomware protection since the server is in control of the backups. Interesting that UrBackup has a server installation option for an ARM 32bit Docker container, as I use a SBC on the LAN as a backup server. Can the UrBackup server send wake on LAN magic packets to clients to wake them for nighttime scheduled backups?